# Dividing container div into columns with CSS

Tags: html, css

Ok, so the code looks like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-one"></div>
    <div class="common"></div>
    <div class="common"></div>
    <div class="common"></div>
    <div class="main-two"></div>
    <div class="common"></div>
    <div class="common"></div>
    <div class="common"></div>
    <div class="main-three"></div>
    <div class="common"></div>
    <div class="common"></div>
    <div class="common"></div>
</div>
```

At the moment all divs create one column in `container` (they all appears one below another with `display: block`). What I want to achieve is: 3 columns, where each contains 1 `main-` div (header- it just appear at the top of the column) and 3 `common` divs which are below `main-` in the code.

Is there any way of doing this with only CSS (no css grid), without creating inner containers or JS? Maybe flex somehow? It's pretty hard for me when I cannot change the structure.

This is how it looks now: https://jsfiddle.net/bh1pk7ty/

And this is how I want it to look: https://jsfiddle.net/z0nwoqsx/

Comment: A table perhaps?

Comment: Why not CSS grid?

Comment: because when you use css grid you have to do everything manually. And, for example, I am not sure how many `common` divs there will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Columns

You can do this with `columns` with your existing markup.

```css
.container {
  columns: 3;
}

[class^="main-"] {
  background: red;
  break-before: column;
}

.common {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-one">main-one</div>
  <div class="common">common 1</div>
  <div class="common">common 1</div>
  <div class="common">common 1</div>
  <div class="common">common 1</div>

  <div class="main-two">main-two</div>
  <div class="common">common 2</div>
  <div class="common">common 2</div>
  <div class="common">common 2</div>
  <div class="common">common 2</div>
  <div class="common">common 2</div>
  <div class="common">common 2</div>
  
  <div class="main-three">main-three</div>
  <div class="common">common 3</div>
  <div class="common">common 3</div>
  <div class="common">common 3</div>
</div>
```

---

## Flexbox

This is probably the best you can do with flexbox unless you can change the structure of your markup, or add some type of extra information to hook into.

**Note**: this does not preserve the `columns` that each `.common` should fall under, as flexbox can only lay each `.common` out in the next available space.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 0 1 33%;
}

[class^="main-"] {
  order: 0;
  background: red
}

.common {
  order: 1;
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-one">main-one</div>
  <div class="common">common 1</div>
  <div class="common">common 1</div>
  <div class="common">common 1</div>
  
  <div class="main-two">main-two</div>
  <div class="common">common 2</div>
  <div class="common">common 2</div>
  <div class="common">common 2</div>
  
  <div class="main-three">main-three</div>
  <div class="common">common 3</div>
  <div class="common">common 3</div>
  <div class="common">common 3</div>
</div>
```

---

## Grid

But then if you can change the markup, you could also just use grid.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

[class^="main-"] {
  background: red;
  //break-before:column;
  // grid-column-start: 1;
}

[class*="-one"] {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
}

[class*="-two"] {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

[class*="-three"] {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

[class^="common-"] {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-one">main-one</div>
  <div class="common-one">common 1</div>
  <div class="common-one">common 1</div>
  <div class="common-one">common 1</div>
  <div class="common-one">common 1</div>

  <div class="main-two">main-two</div>
  <div class="common-two">common 2</div>
  <div class="common-two">common 2</div>
  <div class="common-two">common 2</div>
  <div class="common-two">common 2</div>
  <div class="common-two">common 2</div>
  <div class="common-two">common 2</div>

  <div class="main-three">main-three</div>
  <div class="common-three">common 3</div>
  <div class="common-three">common 3</div>
  <div class="common-three">common 3</div>
</div>
```